# how to give horizontal space in jsp for html and jsp elements?

Tags: html, jsp

```
%>
Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("userid")%>
out.println("\t \t \t \t");
<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
<%
```

> here I have added out.println("\t \t \t \t") but not working and displaying as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating HTML, so structure your output using HTML elements and style them with CSS. For instance:

```
%>
<div style="float: right">
    <a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    Welcome <%= session.getAttribute("userid") %>
</div>
<%
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work :

```
 %>
    <div style="float:left">
            welcome <%= session.getAttribute("userid") %>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right">
            <a href="logout.jsp">Log out</a>
    </div>
    <%
```